# Adding multiple Hyperlinks in a single Excel Cell using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, cells, worksheet

I currently use a macro which has a Form and a Button, and array containing path strings like shown in the following example:

```
array(0)="C:\Users\Dylan\Desktop\Hi.PDF"
array(1)="C:\Users\Dylan\Desktop\Bye.PDF"
array(2)="C:\Users\Dylan\Desktop\Welcome.PDF"
```

On Button click, the content of array is concatenated and placed in a single sentence, separated by comma (,) between the links. With only 1 path/link [array(0)] I can use the VBA code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Hyperlinks.Add array(0)
```

but since there are multiple links in a string, what is the VBA technique to add them all as separate links in the same sentence in the same cell?

Right now I have:

```
for i = 0 to 2
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value & array(i)
next i
```

I need to add all links in one cell.

Comment: Not doable - one link per cell only

Comment: I have edited your question for better clarity. Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can add Embed HTML page with multiple links on it in the cell. Or you can draw a transparent box and remove all fill and add information in that with the links. Both are not actually adding more than one link in a cell but a work around. :-)